# How to find unique values in a column A based by unique users in column B?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which looks like this:

```
df=
['UserId','SessionId','Item_class']
[1       ,34         ,'toy'       ]
[1       ,35         ,'book'      ]
[2       ,36         ,'book'      ]
```

Note that there is a 1:n relationship between UserId and SessionId as 1 user can have multiple session in which they purchase an item.

I need to find out how many unique items a user purchased in an output like this:

```
 df=
    ['UserId','number_items']
    [1       ,2             ]
    [2       ,1             ]
```

I found many topics which discuss only how to get a unique value for a column
 `df.Item_class.unique()` but I didn't find anything that breaks that down by a sub-column, in this case, UserId.

Hope someone can help. thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('UserId').count()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
>>> df.groupby("UserId").Item_class.nunique()
UserId
1    2
2    1
```

It counts unique `Item_class` per `UserID`